# What is meant by saying the following?

Tags: group-theory, functions

$f:\mathbb{Z}_6 \to \mathbb{Z}_3$ is homomorphism induced by the identity map $\mathbb{1}_\mathbb{Z}$, what kind of map are we talking about? Is it: $x \mod 6 \mapsto x \mod 3\,$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. $\mathbb{1}_\mathbb{Z}$ is the identity map $x\mapsto x$. So the induced map from $\mathbb{Z}_6$ to $\mathbb{Z}_3$ is $x \mod 6 \mapsto x \mod 3$. Note that this is only well defined because $6$ is a multiple of $3$.